# Google Sheets Query = Dynamically update as more Form Responses are added

Tags: forms, google-sheets

I have multiple google forms (surveys) that I am linking to a sheet. I used a query

```
=QUERY({'Form Responses 2'!A2:K;'Form Responses 1'!A2:K; 'Form Responses 1.A'!A2:K},"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

What I was wondering, is there are a lot of sheets (like 20), and maybe more coming in;
They are automatically called `Form Responses` as they come in, with the number increasing by one.

How would I do it so that I only need to type `Form Responses` once in the query? Would it be something like

`%orm Response%` ?

as in

```
=QUERY({'%orm Responses%'!A2:K},"select * where Col1 is not null")
```

(obvs that didn't to work, but something like that?)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly there isn't such an option in google sheets. but you may use programmatical generation like:

```
=INDEX("=QUERY({"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, "'"&B1&" "&SEQUENCE(B2)&"'!A2:K")&"}, 
 ""where Col1 is not null"")")
```

[image]

### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/196KVHkSjm3t5KQWNwJUs1r2TSEHIOv4mTPNJ-jZgGpg/edit#gid=0)